# Invalid file name for file monitoring

Tags: c#, asp.net

Any idea on this error? Im using vs 2013 and this comes in when I try to execute Server.Transfer("index.aspx", true); where the index page is wrapped in a master page.

> Exception:Caught: "Invalid file name for file monitoring: 'somefolderpath\MasterPages'. Common reasons for failure include:
>   - The filename is not a valid Win32 file name.
>   - The filename is not an absolute path.
>   - The filename contains wildcard characters.
>   - The file specified is a directory.
>   - Access denied." (System.Web.HttpException)
>   A System.Web.HttpException was caught: "Invalid file name for file monitoring: 'folderpath\MasterPages'. Common reasons for failure include:
>   - The filename is not a valid Win32 file name.
>   - The filename is not an absolute path.
>   - The filename contains wildcard characters.
>   - The file specified is a directory.
>   - Access denied."

Answer (score 1):

Try using this one:
    `Server.Transfer(Server.MapPath("index.aspx"), true);`

Comment: nop.. no luck.. I also tried Server.Transfer(Server.MapPath("index.aspx"), true); and not it says `Exception:Thrown: "Invalid path for child request`